# how to dynamically populate image in propertyPane dropdownOptions?

Tags: spfx-webparts, pnpjs, multi-select

check this image i want to get the same in DropdownOptions like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihfJn.png

i'm getting key and title on the property pane perfectly i just need to display images from list too , i'm newbie in spfx and pnpjs webpart development thanks ,,,,,

```
  results.forEach((item)=>{
    
    this._listFields.push({key: item.ID , text:item.Title , ImageSrc:item.File.Name});
     
  });
        PropertyFieldMultiSelect('GetFrom', {  
              key: 'GetFrom',  
              label: "filter items",  
              options: this._listFields,
              selectedKeys:this.properties.GetFrom,
              
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently PnP control - "PropertyFieldMultiSelect"  does not support image in option.

Currently only key and value is supported.

- Refer this docs for more details.
- [PropertyFieldMultiSelect](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/controls/PropertyFieldMultiSelect/)
- refer the below sample code from documentation.

```
PropertyFieldMultiSelect('multiSelect', {
  key: 'multiSelect',
  label: "Multi select field",
  options: [
    {
      key: "EN",
      text: "EN"
    },
    {
      key: "FR",
      text: "FR"
    },
    {
      key: "NL",
      text: "NL"
    }
  ],
  selectedKeys: this.properties.multiSelect
})
```

Comment: thanks well is there any way create custom property pane to get images in ?

Comment: you can not do it in plane html.

Comment: how i can use to create custom properties pane if possible using noJs framework ?

Comment: Refer the  below article , It will help you

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/sharepoint-spfx-web-part-property-pane/2-property-pane-overview


https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/integrate-with-property-pane

https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/main/samples/react-custompropertypanecontrols/src/webparts/dropdownWithRemoteData/DropdownWithRemoteDataWebPart.ts

Checkout Sample 

https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-webparts/

Comment: thanks brother,,,